# How to request reinforcements

Tags: deadwalk-the-last-war

In Deadwalk: The Last War, how can I request reinforcements from my League? I know I can rally the league to attack a target, and they appear in the League->Reinforcements menu, but how do people get the option to defend in there?

This is on the Android version, but I'm sure it's going to be the same for the iOS version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your enemy is attacking you directly, you will have to ask your league members to help reinforce your city in league chat.

However, if your enemy starts a rally against you, then your league will have the option to donate troops to defend against the rally.

Unfortunately, there is no rally to defend button like there is a rally to attack